# How $e/m$ ratio depend on voltage?

Tags: special-relativity, electrons, mass, charge, voltage

I currently studied about Cathode ray experiment by JJ Thomson.

In that as you know he found an $e/m$ ratio, where $e$ denotes charge of electron and $m$ denotes mass of electron. And this ratio is about **1.758820 × 10¹¹C/kg** under 10,000V battery.

And he said this ratio doesn't depend on nature of gas and electrode presend in cathode tube.

But It *does* depend on Voltage applied to tube.

My teacher told it is *directly
proportional* to voltage with the help of this formulae

[image]

And he also told e/m = e/mv (that is e/m ratio where m is rest mass is equal to e/mv ratio where mv is moving mass)

I can't understand **How e/m ratio is directly proportional to voltage?**

**Does that 'e' in above equation also increases with increase in voltage?**

**How is that e/m or e/mv ratio increase with voltage?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1) Please don't use screenshots and typeset the equations using Mathjax provided by this site. 2) Mass doesn't change with velocity (this is a convention that has been in use for decades). 3) What is $v$ in your formula? Voltage of velocity? Something like $e/m=e/mv$ can't be correct since left-hand side and right-hand side terms don't have the same units.

Comment: Mass is considered invariant now.

Comment: "A is directly proportional to B" means $A=k*B$, where $k$ is some constant. I don't see how in any sense the mass would be "directly proportional to voltage." Even if you meant "charge to relativistic mass" (which is not what people mean when they say charge to mass ratio; they mean charge to rest mass $m_0$). You would start with $(1/2)mv^2=qV$ so $v^2=2qV/m$. Then $m=m_0/\sqrt{1-2qV/mc^2}$. So the relationship is more complicated than "directly proportional." But then there's this equation $e/m = e/mv$ and then I just dont know what you mean. Some clarification would help giving an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Modern physicists [try to only refer to](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/2465) *invariant mass* (also called *rest mass*), which your picture denotes $m_0$, but nowadays it tends to be denoted $m$. The invariant mass is voltage-independent, as is $e$.

That said:

By contrast, the "relativistic mass" concept, which we've largely found unhelpful, is denoted $m$ in your picture. The relation $eV=(m-m_0)c^2$ isn't quite what your teacher said, as it sounds like they implied voltage is proportional to $m$ rather than $m-m_0$.

Comment: So You mean now a days we dont consider mass varies with velocity!? Then how e/m ratio depend on voltage? So as we increase or decrease volatge will it create as if electron number increase mass will increase too proportionally. Please explain it too in your answer. Thank you

Comment: @ShinchanNohara I already explained it: relativistic mass depends on velocity, invariant mass doesn't, but the former notion of mass has long been considered unhelpful.

Comment: So will e/m ratio Constant(as you said in para 1 last lines)??? Irrespective of volatge. Just This i wanna ask. Thanks again for ur answer

Comment: @ShinchanNohara Yes. The term "charge to mass ratio" means charge to invariant mass ratio $q/m_0$. And modern physicists try not to use the term "relativistic mass" ($m=m_0/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$) to explain why it takes more force to speed something up which is already close to the speed of light. Instead we explain this effect by modifying Newton's equation $f=(m_0/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2})a$. It does not depend on voltage, or electron speed, or anything else. It is an unchanging property of the universe, which is why experiments spend so much time measuring it precisely.

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher was wrong. The charge-to-mass ratio is a fundamental property of the electron, independent of its environment. Even if you take the (unfashionable and needlessly confusing) perspective that mass varies with speed, the variation $m=\gamma m_0=\left(1-(v/c) ^2\right)^{-1/2}m_0$ is nonlinear, while "directly proportional" implies a linear relationship.

In Thomson's experiment, a beam of electrons passed briefly through a region of strong electric field:

[image: cathode ray tube]
([source](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Thomson_cathode_ray_exp.gif#mw-jump-to-license))

If the angle of deflection is small, then the transverse impulse $∆p=F∆t$ is directly proportional to the applied voltage. The *displacement of the beam spot* is then directly proportional to the voltage (also in the small-angle limit).

Answer (score -1):

$\frac{1}{2} m v^{2} = e \cdot V$

Over here $e$ is electron charge, $m$ is mass of electron, $v$ is velocity of electron and $V$ is voltage.

So, obviously your teacher did a mistake on his end. $e/m$ is inversely proportional to the voltage.

And let me tell you one more thing. The concept of relativistic speed can not be applied here because of 2 reasons:

- Electron can't achieve the relativistic speed.
- Here you are applying formulae of the classical physics which will fail if you use the mass and energy conversion.

Comment: Why can't electrons achieve a relativistic speed? Given that the rest mass is 511keV it is actually pretty easy to get relativistic electrons. Far easier than relativistic protons.

Comment: In addition to Jon Custer's comment... "is inversely proportional to the voltage"... how? In the end, even if I thought "charge to mass ratio" meant "charge to relativistic mass ratio" (it doesnt; it means charge to rest mas), I would get $e/m=e\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}/m_0=e\sqrt{1-2eV/mc^2}/m_0$. The term "A is inversely proportional to B" specifically means $A=k/B$ where $k$ is a constant. This relationship is not that simple.

Answer (score -3):

I Think When voltage Is increased Velocity of electron also increases and according to theory of relativity when speed is close to speed of light the mass charges and i think mass decreases and when Mass in motion decreases than e/m ratio also increases in nut shell we can say that e/m ratio is directly proportional to Voltage

Comment: No, that isn’t how it works.

Comment: Ok dude sorry from my side